# How can I express 'repeat this part' in a regular expression?

Tags: python, regex

Suppose I want to match a string like this:

> 123(432)123(342)2348(34)

I can match digits like `123` with `[\d]*` and `(432)` with `\([\d]+\)`.

How can match the whole string by repeating either of the 2 patterns?

*I tried `[[\d]* | \([\d]+\)]+`, but this is incorrect.*

*I am using python re module.*

Comment: Do you consider input such as `22398742934`, or `(23423)(234234)` or `(23432423)23423490` valid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need this regex:

```
"^(\d+|\(\d+\))+$"
```

and to avoid catastrophic backtracking you need to change it to a regex like this:

```
"^(\d|\(\d+\))+$"
```

Comment: You will run into catastrophic backtracking with this regex.

Comment: This works for me. What is the catastrophic backtracking?

Comment: @shA.t: OP wants to validate the string (or so I think). Regardless of OP's intention, since you add `^` and `$`, the regex can only be used to validate string or match valid lines. If the string is invalid, the engine has to exhaust all possibilities in the regex, which is where catastrophic backtracking can occur.

Comment: One easy fix is to change the regex to `^(\d|\(\d+\))+$`.

Comment: Thanks, I got it now ;).

Comment: Also, the OP doesn't need capturing, so the non-capturing version `(?:` should be used. See [Regular Expression Syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax)

Comment: @NeoWang: With the `+`, you have `^(\d+)+$`, which is the classic example of catastrophic backtracking - it will try all permutation of splitting a substring of consecutive digits.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a character class to match the whole of string :

```
[\d()]+
```

But if you want to match the separate parts in separate groups you can use `re.findall` with a spacial regex based on your need, for example :

```
>>> import re
>>> s="123(432)123(342)2348(34)"
>>> re.findall(r'\d+\(\d+\)',s)
['123(432)', '123(342)', '2348(34)']
>>>
```

Or :

```
>>> re.findall(r'(\d+)\((\d+)\)',s)
[('123', '432'), ('123', '342'), ('2348', '34')]
```

Or you can just use `\d+` to get all the numbers :

```
>>> re.findall(r'\d+',s)
['123', '432', '123', '342', '2348', '34']
```

If you want to match the patter `\d+\(\d+\)` repeatedly you can use following regex :

```
(?:\d+\(\d+\))+
```

Comment: The parentheses have to be balanced, so `[\d()]+` doesn't work. And I want to match the whole string, not segments.

Comment: @NeoWang How `[\d()]+` doesn't work? it will match all the string, and what you mean by *parentheses have to be matched*?

Comment: @Kasramvd: He probably means parentheses have to be balanced (without nesting, I assume)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it with this pattern:

```
^(?=.)\d*(?:\(\d+\)\d*)*$
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/wI9jE5/1)

`(?=.)` ensures there is at least one character (if you want to allow empty strings, remove it).

`\d*(?:\(\d+\)\d*)*` is an unrolled sub-pattern. Explanation: With a bactracking regex engine, when you have a sub-pattern like `(A|B)*` where A and B are mutually exclusive (or at least when the end of A or B doesn't match respectively the beginning of B or A), you can rewrite the sub-pattern like this: `A*(BA*)*` or `B*(AB*)*`. For your example, it replaces `(?:\d+|\(\d+\))*`
This new form is more efficient: it reduces the steps needed to obtain a match, it avoids a great part of the eventual bactracking.

Note that you can improve it more, if you emulate an [atomic group](http://regular-expressions.mobi/atomic.html) `(?>....)` with [this trick](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/mimic-atomic-groups) `(?=(....))\1` that uses the fact that a lookahead is naturally atomic:

```
^(?=.)(?=(\d*(?:\(\d+\)\d*)*))\1$
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/wI9jE5/2) *(compare the number of steps needed with the previous version and check the debugger to see what happens)*

Note: if you don't want two consecutive numbers enclosed in parenthesis, you only need to change the quantifier `*` with `+` inside the non-capturing group and to add `(?:\(\d+\))?` at the end of the pattern, before the anchor `$`:

```
^(?=.)\d*(?:\(\d+\)\d+)*(?:\(\d+\))?$
```

or

```
^(?=.)(?=(\d*(?:\(\d+\)\d+)*(?:\(\d+\))?))\1$
```

Comment: Thanks for such detailed explanation! Now I know how powerful RE can be.